# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..1, inclusive: 2

Tags: flutter, search, dart, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search

I want to make a search onto my firestore items that having 3 fields A, B, C. when I click my search it will show that it is related to my alphabet and if I didn't use uppercase it also gives me  same result which in case of uppercase.

My code is

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fmiantrader/SearchService.dart';
import 'SearchService.dart';

class Serchitemsbymod extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id='serchitemsbymod';
  @override
  _SerchitemsbymodState createState() => _SerchitemsbymodState();
}

class _SerchitemsbymodState extends State<Serchitemsbymod> {



  List<String> store=[];
  var q=[];
  var t=[];

  initiateserach(value){
    if(value.length==0){
      setState(() {
        q=[];
        t=[];
      }

      );
    }
    var cp=value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+value.substring(1);
    if(q.length==0 && value.length==1){
      SearchService().searchByName(value).then((QuerySnapshot docs){
        for(int i=0;i <= docs.documents.length;i++){
          q.add(docs.documents[i].data);

        }
      }
      );
    }
    else{
      t=[];
      q.forEach((element){
        if(element['A'].startsWith(cp)){
          setState(() {
            t.add(element);
          });
        }
      }
      );
    };}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Mian Traders'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (val){
              initiateserach(val);
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefix: IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },),
              contentPadding:   EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
              hintText: 'Serach Items',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 25.0
              ),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)

              )

            ),
          ),),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
          GridView.count(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            primary: false,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children:t.map((element){
              return buildResult(element);

            }).toList()),

        ]));

  }
}

Widget buildResult(data) {

  return Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
    elevation: 2.0,
    child: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(data['items'],
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 20.0,
        ),),

      ),
    ),

  );
}
```

and the base of search is due to another field that is d (as key for search). my SearchService() class code is

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SearchService{
  searchByName(String searchField){
    return Firestore.instance.collection('items')
        .where('d',
        isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0,1).toUpperCase())
        .getDocuments();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by an invalid range trying to be read. This error occurs when you run out of values when iterating over a List of objects. You need to identify where the RangeError occurs.

If the error is being thrown on the GridView, it's likely there's no more data to be displayed compared to the expected Widgets on screen. Make sure that the item count of Widgets matches with the List being displayed. If you just need to fill out the empty space in the Grid, you can just use `return Container();`